# Create cloud textured effect in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, texture

I want to create an effect/color like this image of the cloud in the Parse.com logo. It is not quite white, and seems to have a texture. I am new to illustrator, but have a white "cloud" made thanks to some other tutorials. How do I proceed?

[image: cloud example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can help to bring out the details of a subtle texture by altering the levels of the original image. I used Photoshop to do this:

[image: Altered levels in Photoshop]

This shows us that the cloud has a very slight gradient applied to it as well as an inner glow. Both of these can be added as an effect in Illustrator. The opacity of the cloud is also slightly reduced which might add that texture you're referring to.